# Обновление таблицы после вычитания из нее ингридиентов

Tags: access, delphi, sql

Привет. У меня есть такая БД (http://pixs.ru/showimage/Bezimyanni_8811057_11962665.png).
У меня есть форма с кнопкой, по нажатию которой мне необходимо, чтобы ингредиенты (поле "KolichestvoIngridientov" таблица "SostavBluda"), содержащиеся в Блюде (таблица "Bluda") вычитались из поля "KolichestvoNaSklade" таблицы "Ingridienty"...
Плюс ко всему кнопка находится на одной форме, а таблица на другой.
Ну вот собственно как-то так. Помогите пожалуйста это реализовать! Пробовала через SQL-запрос, но запуталась в объединении таблиц и связи форм...

Comment: У меня есть претензии к структуре таблиц - у вас нельзя заказать несколько блюд одновременно. А так все просто:

Заказ из меню джойнится с составом блюда по идентификатору, из таблицы ингредиентов добывается складской идентификатор, осуществляется группировка по складским идентификаторам с суммированием количества, после чего производится джойн с таблицей остатков, в которую и вносятся изменения.

После успешного пересчета остатков обновляете форму с остатками.

Comment: @maxleo, не хочу показаться наглой, но вот так в словесной форме я так и предполагала, а вот именно перевести все это в программную реализацию не могу...
Кстати, несколько блюд у меня можно заказывать...Они все потом в корзине отображаются....

Comment: @Анна_Мазурова, так и переводите:

Update b set ostatok = ostatok - kolvo
From (select id_nal, sum(kolvo) kolvo
From... 
Group by id_nal
) a inner join sklad b on b.id_nal = a.id_nal

Разберетесь.

Comment: @maxleo,спасибо))))Буду разбираться!

Comment: Написала в обработчик нажатия кнопки вот таким образом, про группировку немного не поняла, зачем она нужна?
Теперь по нажатию кнопки пишет,что пропущен оператор....

    begin
    ADOQuery1.Close;
    ADOQuery1.sql.Clear;
    ADOQuery1.sql.Add('update Ingridienty set KolichestvoNaSklade=KolichestvoNaSklade-KolichestvoIngridienta from Ingridienty Inner Join (Bluda Inner Join SostavBluda ON Bluda.ID_B=SostavBluda.NameBluda) ON Ingridienty.ID_I=SostavBluda.NameIngridient');
    ADOQuery1.Open;
    end;

Comment: @Анна_Мазурова, вы написали не то, что я озвучил:

Update b set...
From (zakaz
inner join bluda on...
Inner join sostav on...
Inner join ingredients on...
Group by...) a
inner join sklad b on...
Where zakaz.id = prm_id 

Группировка нужна на случай одинаковых ингредиентов в разных блюдах заказа.